# How create proportionally views with autolayout for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have to make a new app where the designer make this type of graphics:

iPhone 4:
[image: iPhone 4]

iPhone 5:
[image: iPhone 5]

As you can see in the iPhone 4 I have a smaller header than iPhone 5 (also the subviews like the bird and text and smaller). How can I do this with autolayout? I used the aspect ratio without success :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to use proportional height constraint and / or proportional width constraint. See an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set a vertical space constraint from the top of your UIImageView to the top layout guide.

Then set an Aspect Ratio constraint on the UIImageView. Set the multiplier to whatever ratio you need. For example 4:3. The ratio is width:height. That should do it.

Comment: Note that this assumes your entire header is an image. If not, this won't work.

Comment: Thank you Mike I will try. But why this can't work if my header is a UIView instead of a UIImageView?

Comment: I might be wrong about that. Give it a try and see.